# How to check recieved parameter in javascript function an instance of user defined object?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function with a variable 'object' which may recieve any of two types of object ,say x and y object

```
function myFunction(object){alert(instanceof object) };
```

Is there something like this?
It should alert x or y

Comment: what is your use case?What you want to really do?

Comment: You could try `object.constructor.name`

Comment: `if (object instanceof x) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: I have an if condition  based on the instance of the object

Answer (score 2):

> Is there something like this? It should alert x or y

Yes:

```
alert(object instanceof TheConstructorYouWantToCheckAgainst);
```

If I read your question correctly, your constructors are `x` and `y` (convention would be to use an upper case first letter). So for instance:

```
function x() {
}
function y() {
}
var o = new x();
console.log(o instanceof x); // true
console.log(o instanceof y); // false
```

If you want to get `"x"` from `object` when it's created via `new x`, you can't reliably in ES5 and before. In ES2015 (aka "ES6") and above, functions have a `name` property which is set in a large variety of ways (even when the function was created with an "anonymous" function expression). So if `x` has a name (it's still possible for it not to), and if the inheritance chain has been correctly set up, `object.constructor.name` will give you `"x"`. But I wouldn't rely on it, because people mess up `constructor` when doing  inheritance chains *all the time*.

Comment: Thanks for the Info!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different solution depending on what you need

In the following code I used *X* object. Replace the *X* by *Y* for the other case

```
object instanceof X;     // == true
object.constructor.name;        // == "X"

X.prototype.isPrototypeOf(object);  // == true
```

Comment: See comments in my answer about `object.constructor.name`. It isn't reliable (people mess up `constructor` all the time), and doesn't officially exist at all in ES5 and earlier.

Comment: When would you use `X.prototype.isPrototypeOf(object)` rather than `object instanceof X`?

Comment: Yes, my point was that that information should be directly in the answer.

Comment: I should clarify my comment above: People mess up `constructor` all the time, and `name` on functions doesn't officially exist at all in ES5 and earlier (`constructor` does!).